# Concerns over the D&D Translations question

Tags: discussion, list-questions

I have concerns with the quality of the [D&D Translations question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/60341/which-translations-of-dd-3-5-use-meters) and the answers it has received so far.

As far as I can see it is going to be virtually impossible to guarantee a complete list as required, as it would be necessary to have access to all available translations to be able to compile one. As things stand, I believe the question encourages answers such as those that has already been given, with a single language that meets the criteria in the question.

The problem is, this does not answer the question as stated, yet one of the answers has already received 3 votes. If we leave things as they are I can see it encouraging similar answers, each with a single language in, none of which by themselves actually answer the question.

It seems to me that this is effectively a list question in disguise, and if it were more obvious then it would closed, yet it has received no VTC at all. Is there anything we can/should do about this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, that's a (small) problem (and potentially a slightly larger precedent-setting one too). List questions can be a problem for a few reasons, most often due to being unbounded, but also if the answers will just be minor variations on each other, as here.

As far as I can tell, the actual "problem" is curiosity about how metric units work within the system, such as the size of grid squares and the listed weights of items.

I've edited the question to make it *not* ask about *which* translations use metric, as that's almost useless (even if it's a tiny bit useful, it's not a question that is suited to the SE format). I've made it instead a direct question about how the units are used in the system. This presumes that the metric-using translations all use metric similarly or identically, but my guess is that variations will be minor at best — and where they are different, that does merit a new answer.

---

That still leaves the answers. They should be editable to simply say how metric is used in *a* translation, the translation being used as an example of how d20 handles metric conversion, instead of just listing off a translation that checks the "uses metric" box.

However, reviewing them in light of the edited question, they don't actually seem like they need edits. With the new "how does metric work?" focus of the question, in context they read as "here's an example translation that does, and here's what it says about how metric works," rather than a submission to a crowdsourced list.